# Take screenshot with Calabash iOS and save it to a physical device

Tags: ios, automation, calabash-ios

Is it possible to take a screenshot on a physical device and save the picture on the device? Basically I'm looking for the same functionality of doing Home+Lock (which takes a photo of the screen).
I need this because I require to have stored a photo on the cellphone to interact with the integrated gallery of my program.

Comment: You want to take a screenshot of a UIView ?

Comment: Actually I was hoping to take a screenshot of the whole screen and save it on the phone. To do a parallelism, what I do to solve this on calabash-android is to use the following command: system("adb shell input keyevent 120") which calls to the keyevent on the phone to take a screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

**NO**, There is no option to `take screenshot` of device lock screen.

**No**, There is no option to store screenshot in device.